# Spell Breaking Chain used by axe wielding hero

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to find out the name of the fantasy novel(s) where the male hero used an axe and had a spell breaking chain he kept wrapped around his left arm. He always referred to his axe as a brute force weapon as opposed to a sword which was something more finessed. I believe he had a female companion as well.

Answer (score 1):

This pretty much matches the Vlad Taltos series by Steven Brust.  The more-or-less Hero, Vlad Taltos, has a chain Spellbreaker which he carries on his arm in a number of the books and uses to, well, break spells.  I think he's used an axe, but certainly prefers a sword. He has had a female companion.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Brust#Vlad_Taltos

The problem with this identification is that if you *had* read this series, it's hard to believe that's all you'd remember as it's fairly minor detail in a very complex and well-written world.

Comment: He never used an axe

Comment: Also sounds like the 'Hawk and Fisher' series by Simon Green. Hawk only has one eye, so can't use a sword. His axe has the power to cut through spells. His companion is a tall blonde woman called Isobel Fisher.

Comment: Vlad was a swordsman with a smartass flying reptile named Lyosh for a companion.  Vlad does have occasional human female companions, but is often alone.  Like K Dog wrote, he doesn't use an axe.